# Javascript converting YYMMDD formatted string into date object

Tags: javascript, html

This is probably a trivial question, but I'm trying to look for the most efficient way to do this.

I am given a string in this format "20130914" from a servlet and I need to create a javascript date object from it.

From what I know, date object accepts ISO format for strings so I need to append dashes in between my year,month and date like this "2013-09-14"

I could use .splice function to insert dashes in between the year,month and date but I feel like there has to be an easier solution for this trivial question. Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: I think, as you mentioned,  you have to parse the string yourself. like.. var year = mydatestr.substring(0,4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, there is no big problem in writing simple code to do common tasks.

If you find yourself performing a lot of date calculations [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is a very small (5kb) library that handles dates just like that.

For example, what you need in moment can be written as:

```
moment("20130914", "YYYYMMDD");
```

Comment: Yes, I'll be handling a lot of date calculations. Thanks for recommending a great library.

Answer (score 3):

Because I am in love with regex:

```
var rawDate = '20130914';
console.log(new Date(rawDate.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/,"$1-$2-$3")));
//Output: Sat Sep 14 2013 12:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain and simple JS:

```js
var input = "20130914";
var date = new Date(input.substr(0, 4), input.substr(4, 2) - 1, input.substr(6, 2));
console.log(date.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than parsing a string to create another string to be parsed by the built–in parser, you can get the parts and give them directly to the Date constructor:

```js
let s = '20130914';

// Parse string in YYYYMMDD format to Date object
function parseYMD(s) {
  let b = s.match(/\d\d/g);
  return new Date(b[0]+b[1], b[2]-1, b[3]);
}

console.log(parseYMD(s).toString());
```